# error: aggregate value used where an integer was expected

Tags: c, linux, printf, unions, format-specifiers

I am having following union

```
union data {
     uint64_t val;
     struct{
     ....
     }
};
```

and I have a function

```
func(union data mydata[])
{
    printf("%llu",(uint64_t)mydata[0]); // Here is the error
}
```

When i compile this code it is giving following error

```
error: aggregate value used where an integer was expected
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are failing to access a field of the indexed union array: `mydata[0]` is a value of type `union data`, and can't be cast to `uint64_t`.

You need to access the proper union member:

```
printf("%" PRIu64, mydata[0].val);
```

to select the `uint64_t` value. No need for the cast.

Also: Use `PRIu64` to portably print 64-bit values, you can't assume that `%llu` is the right format specifier.

Comment: I think suggest OP `PRIu64` also

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan True, I edited that fix into the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Vote for alerting me to the existence of PRIu64 etc :)

Answer (score 4):

The "dirty" solution to access the first member of the `n`<sup>th</sup> element of the array of unions pointed to by `mydata`  as an `int64_t` ***without*** knowing its name is:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

union data 
{
  uint64_t val;
  ...
};

func(union data mydata[])
{ 
  size_t n = 3;
  printf("%"PRIu64, *((uint64_t *)(mydata + n));     
}
```

This works as the first member's address of a union or struct is guaranteed to be the same as the address of the union or struct itself.